# Tron address hex to base58

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, cryptojs

I am having trouble to convert Tron address hex to base58.
I am using the default base58 decoder with crypto library in nodejs but it doesn't convert to the correct address..
Any help?

Comment: Can you please share the code and address you are trying to convert, as well as the address you expect? (can generate a temp one if you're worried about privacy).

Comment: It was an API that gave me the hex address then I needed to convert it to real address but I found another API which gives me the address directly without converting, so I don't need to convert anymore

Comment: This is in Java, but I need in JS..!
https://github.com/tronprotocol/documentation/blob/master/TRX/Tron-overview.md

address = 41||sha3[12,32): 415a523b449890854c8fc460ab602df9f31fe4293f 
    sha256_0 = sha256(address): 06672d677b33045c16d53dbfb1abda1902125cb3a7519dc2a6c202e3d38d3322 
    sha256_1 = sha256(sha256_0): 9b07d5619882ac91dbe59910499b6948eb3019fafc4f5d05d9ed589bb932a1b4 
    checkSum = sha256_1[0, 4): 9b07d561 
    addchecksum = address || checkSum: 415a523b449890854c8fc460ab602df9f31fe4293f9b07d561 
    base58Address = Base58(addchecksum): TJCnKsPa7y5okkXvQAidZBzqx3QyQ6sxMW

Answer (score 1):

The below code does the trick:

```
const HEX_PREFIX = '41';

exports.hexAddressToBase58 = (hexAddress) => {
    let retval = hexAddress;
    try {
        let tronWeb = getTronWeb();
        if (hexAddress.startsWith("0x")) {
            hexAddress = HEX_PREFIX + hexAddress.substring(2);
        }
        let bArr = tronWeb.utils['code'].hexStr2byteArray(hexAddress);
        retval = tronWeb.utils['crypto'].getBase58CheckAddress(bArr);
    } catch (e) {
        //Handle
    }
    return retval;
}
```